# Has anyone ever had problems with a 2 day diacetyl rest at room temperature?

Tags: fermentation, temperature, lager, diacetyl-rest

Say 70 - 74°­F (21 - 24°C) I normally do what the books say and rest somewhere in the 60s but this means brining my fermentation freezer up to that temperature.  I am mostly an Ale brewer so normally this is not a problem as I only have one lager fermenting at a time.  Just curious what other people are doing.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is exactly what I do. I move my fermenter from the basement (~50°F) to the study (~70°F) and leave it for 2-3 days before racking it to a keg for the lagering fridge.

Since primary fermentation is done and most of the sugar has already been metabolized, there's little or no danger of creating estery off-flavors from the higher fermentation temp. That's more of a worry at the beginning, when fermentation is first taking off and the yeast are thriving on all the sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Those temps are not a problem at all for a d rest.